# Getting specific operations in R for loop based on list values size

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
T1 <- list(t1, id_list=list(), Values=c())
T2 <- list(t2, id_list=list(), Values=c())

values1 = as.numeric(as.vector(values1))
T1$Values = values1
n.id.list1 = length(sort(unique(values1)))
order.list1 = sort(unique(values1))
for ( i in 1:n.id.list1) {
  id1 =  order.list1[i]
  T1$id_list[[i]] <- which(values1==id1) 
}
```

same for T2:

```
values2 = as.numeric(as.vector(values2))
T2$Values = values2
n.id.list2 = length(sort(unique(values2)))
order.list2 = sort(unique(values2))
for ( i in 1:n.id.list2) {
  id2 =  order.list2[i]
  T2$id_list[[i]] <- which(values2==id2)
}

a <- length(T1$id_list)
b <- length(T2$id_list)
size_lists<-matrix(0,2,max(a,b))
```

Lists Size:

```
for (i in 1:a){
  size_lists[1,i] <- length(T1$id_list[[i]])
}
for (j in 1:b){
  size_lists[2,j] <- length(T2$id_list[[j]])
}
```

Number of matching between lists:

```
for (i in 1:a) {
  for (j in 1:b){

    size_matching[i,j] <- length(intersect(T1$id_list[[i]], T2$id_list[[j]])
  }
}
```

And finally I calculate conditional probabilities between lists:

```
for (i in 1:a) {
  for (j in 1:b) {
    if(size_lists[1,i] > 0 & (size_lists[2,j]/size_lists[1,i] > 0.5)) {

      match[i,j] <- round((size_matching[i,j]/size_lists[1,i]),digits=2)
    } else {
      match[i,j] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

I want to calculate these *match[i,j]* only for specific List Sizes, as I defined above, to simplify the process. My idea was to order the lists by decreasing size and calculate `match`  for some **top K** lists by size, but i can´t manage to do it.

I tried ordering `values1` and `values2` using `table`, but it doesn´t really worked for what I had in mind. I also tried to include a ratio between list sizes (the `& (size_lists[2,j]/size_lists[1,i] > 0.5)` above), but threshold value depends on the lists.

Edit:

Concerning the comment of MrFlick:

I have 2 lists, L1 and L2,  at two different timepoints, t1 and t2. At each timepoint, the input gives the membership of those lists('Values' lists), ie, for some class, it gives the belonging group it is in.

e.g.:

```
color   values1(t1) values2(t2)

white   1   2
blue    2   2
red         1       1
orange  2   NA
violet  2   4
brown   NA  2
black   1   3
purple  3   3
green   3   2
grey    2   2
yellow  1   NA
gold    NA  1
pink    1   1
silver  3   3
darkred 1   3
```

The desired output is a list describing the transitions between t1 and t2. The problem is I want to limit the calculations on conditional probabilities (It calculates them for every pair of class) based on lists size. For instance, the class with higher membership in t1 only runs match[i,j] for the top5 highest classes in size in t2. Like I said, I tried using some ratio between list sizes, but it doesn´t really work.

Comment: You forgot to close bracket in last for lop...

Comment: You´re right, thank you! It´s closed on my code though

Comment: I removed your"**" because that's the `^` operator in `R`; made an explicit reference to that code snippet.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you are trying to do as your code seems  "un-R-like". Can you describe in words (not code) what you are trying to accomplish? Or can you at least include sample input (`t1` and `t2` values) as well as your desired output to make it clear where your current implementation is failing?

Comment: edited. hope it is clearer now. Thanks